# Deselect checkbox on click of a button

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, javascript, aura

I have the following code in my lightning component

```
 <lightning:input type="checkbox" label="Life" aura:id="checkboxField"
                             value="{!v.isLifeChecked}" 
                             onchange="{!c.handleLifeCheckboxCheck}"/> 

 <lightning:button label="Clear"
                                  class="slds-button slds-m-right_x-small"
                                  onclick="{!c.onClear}" iconPosition="right"/>
```

and the following code in the helper

```
onClear : function(component, event, helper) {
    component.find("checkboxField").set("v.value", false);
},
```

My isssue here is that, on click of the clear button, the checkbox does not get deselected.

I also tried setting

**isLifeChecked** as **false** in jscontroller, but that does not work either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the attribute for that in lightning:input is `checked` (not value) for checkbox type

```
<lightning:input type="checkbox" label="Life" aura:id="checkboxField"
                         checked="{!v.isLifeChecked}" 
                         onchange="{!c.handleLifeCheckboxCheck}"/>
```

Also in javascript you have to set `checked` only

```
component.find("checkboxField").set("v.checked", false);
```

Comment: i did not not change the value attribute, but without the value attribute I will not be able to perform some functionalities. The v.checked wroks perfectly.